# Confused by AngularUI modal documentation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am new to Angular and confused by the documentation for AngularUI modal dialog. I don't see how the code presented there would fit in with the controller for the main page, or how a button on the main page, when clicked, would open the modal dialog.

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Is `ModalDemoCtrl` supposed to be *appended* to the controllers of the main page's app?

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

  var ModalDemoCtrl = function($scope, $modal, $log) {
        <snip>
  }
  myApp.controller("ModalDemoCtrl");
```

or is the `ModalDemoCtrl` function object simply nested within the main page's controller?

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

 myApp.controller("MainPageCtrl", function($scope, $modal, $log) {

       var ModalDemoCtrl = function($scope, $modal, $log) {
        <snip>
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is a regular controller:

```
var modal = $modal.open({
       templateUrl: 'deleteDialog.html',
       controller: 'deleteDialogController'
});

modal.result.then(function () {

});
```

deleteDialogController.js file:

```
appModule.controller("deleteDialogController", [ "$scope", "$modalInstance",
    function ($scope, $modalInstance)
    {
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close();
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: Totally agree with _Basically it is a regular controller_

Comment: Do the main page and the html fragment have the same controller? Also, in the config, you're feeding `controller` property a string, the name of the controller, whereas docs have an object-reference.

Comment: @Tim it can be controller in different file or inline definition http://plnkr.co/edit/l56203bfNiibGeB4CfdW?p=preview , i prefer the different file option

Comment: Finally got it to work!  By removing `<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html"> from the html snippet, when the snippet is stored in a separate file.

Comment: Thanks @MajoB, that is helpful. But I do not understand `templateUrl` in your example.

Comment: @Tim templateUrl is a reference to <script type="text/ng-template" id="deleteFavoriteDialog.html"></script>